# Obtain PlotLabel from Plot

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have a very simple question that I cant find answer: how do I extract the PlotLabel from an existing plot? For example

```
plotwithLabel = Plot[x, {x, 1, 2}, PlotLabel -> "This is Label"]
```

Any way to get the text "This is Label"?

Comment: `Cases[plotwithLabel, _String, Infinity][[-1]]`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) is returning a [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) object, with the label specified in its [`Options`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Options.html).  Retrieve the options with

```
In[2]:= Options[plotwithLabel, PlotLabel]

Out[2]= {PlotLabel -> "This is Label"}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
PlotLabel /. plotwithLabel[[2]]
```

> "This is Label"

Comment: does the use of the 2nd slot only work because it is the second argument of plotwithLabel? Hah wow this is actually a pretty keen answer, I anticipate this is not an expected use-case or combination, but it just fits so nicely together, hah! Love it +1!

Comment: @CATrevillian, thank you for the vote. Second `Part` of the the graphics object produced by `Plot` contains the graphics options. So we can get the options using `Options@Plot[...]` or using `Last@Plot[...]`.

Comment: Ah right right, but is it not dependent upon ordering of the options given? I ask for this clarification because within the `Options` returned, I find `PlotLabel` near the end of the list. Though, thinking about this further, with `ReplaceAll`, I suppose I understand that it would only catch the portion of values returned that matches the input, `PlotLabel`.

Answer (score 5):

```
plotwithLabel = Plot[x, {x, 1, 2}, PlotLabel -> "This is Label"];
PlotLabel /. Cases[plotwithLabel, _Rule, All]
```

> "This is Label"

If you look at the output of e.g. `SequenceForm@ InputForm@ plotwithLabel`, you will see the internal representation of the plot as a `Graphics` object. You will note that it contains many options expressed as `Rule`s (i.e. `OptionName -> optionValue`, like maybe `PlotRange -> All`). Such expressions are actually represented as `Rule[PlotRange, All]` in their native form, so they have head `Rule`. 
My `Cases` expression extracts all possible `Rule[something, something]` expressions at `All` levels inside the plot's internal representation. It then uses them as replacement rules in a `ReplaceAll` expression (`/.`) to fish out the value of the one you are interested in, i.e. `PlotLabel`.

Comment: Thank you, I wish I could accept multiple answer..  I like your answer a lot, it looks very simple. But could you please explain why it works? I'm pretty lost

Comment: @Histoscienology I added an explanation in the answer; hope this might help.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @JasonB.’s answer, which, while relatively simple-looking, still returns a rule which requires further operation in order to retrieve the `PlotLabel`. Other answers seem confusing, though they will work on lesser versions than when `Association` was introduced in v10. I propose this solution which is simple, direct, and easily gives the desired output of `PlotLabel` in a single line.

```
(Association@Options@plotwithLabel)[PlotLabel]
(* “This is Label” *)
```

`Association` turns the `List` of `Rule`s returned by `Options` into an `Association` from which you can simply & directly request the `PlotLabel`.

Comment: `PlotLabel//Association@Options@plotwithLabel` uses 2 less characters to give the same output, not to play code-golf or anything, but...

Comment: Another thing to consider would be Lookup[Options[plotwithLabel], PlotLabel]

Comment: @JasonB. Aha! `Lookup` is nice :) The more I learn, the more I know I know nearly nothing about WL. I feel like `OptionValue[plotwithLabel[[2]],PlotLabel]` should work without having to use `Part`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the several mechanism of filtering data. `PlotLabel` is an option for Plot. The options in a Plot that you have made are in the second part of plotwithlabel. That is to say, one way is

```
In[29]:= Cases[plotwithLabel[[2]], Rule[PlotLabel, x_] -> x] // First
Out[29]= This is Label
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In[2]:= Cases[Unevaluated[Plot[x, {x, 1, 2}, PlotLabel -> "This is Label"]], 
     HoldPattern[PlotLabel -> _]]
Out[2]= {PlotLabel -> "This is Label"}
```